# Distort plane by multiple curves

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

Not sure if this is a good way to go about things; so any alternative approaches are welcome too.

I would like to distort a plane using multiple curves

[image]

So the below plane would be bent "into" each of the curves in the image.

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: A simple plane like that can't be deformed (by curves or otherwise) because it has no subdivisions and hence no deformable geometry that can be bent. Deforming with curves generally works well for linear elongated objects with main deformation along one axis. Deforming with two curves may be tricky and you are probably best off modelling it manually or through other means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but as Duarte said in his comment it may be painful and requires some experimenting.
[image]

3 important things that you have to do:

- subdivide your *plane* several times (being in *Edit Mode* press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*)
- make sure the *plane* and both *curves* have the *origin points* placed in the same position
- apply the transformations for all the objects (being in *Object Mode* press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Apply Rot&Scale*)

[image]

Now select the plane and give it two ***Curve modifiers*** (each one should have a different *curve* set as a target). Dissable the second modifier (eye icon). Check which deformation axis fits the first one. Fit the *plane* to the *curve*. Now enable the second one and do the same step as with the first one.
[image]

Comment: oh wow; thank you for the detailed walk through!!!