# Bend a plane into a television screen using curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

Is it possible to turn a plane into a convex shape using the curve modifier?  I want to shape it to look like a vintage television screen.  I tried to do this but it just made it look like a crumpled piece of paper.

The reason I want to use the modifier rather than a curved mesh is because I want to use video as a texture (thus the single face of the plane).

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a simple deform modifier?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79210/distort-plane-by-multiple-curves

Comment: Deform modifier might work...I'll try that!

Comment: @PaulGonet unfortunately I can't subdivide as I need a single face to apply the video as a texture.  Unless there's a work around?

Comment: The plane can't be bent as long as it's single quad or whatever but one face. Either it's subdivided plane (quads preferably) and can be bent with any tool you can imagine or it's a flat polygon.

Comment: @MrZak ah OK.  I'll have to try to fake the texture behind the screen then.

Comment: Also, you don't need to fake anything, making the plane subdivided doesn't invalidate having a video (or anything else) as texture, you can unwrap the plane before subdividing and apply the texture, or you can map the texture correctly afterwards, either way will work.

Comment: Ohhh right!  Sorry I don't know what I was thinking...that's totally true